# Check if test failed in afterEach of Jest

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, jestjs

When one of my [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) tests fails I want to store a screenshot, but only when it fails.

Here is a piece of my test code as an example, the **`!passed`** part in the afterEach is not working.

```
describe('Page', () => {  
  it('should contain Text in the header', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const page = new Page(driver);

    // Act
    await page.open();

    // Assert
    expect(await page.getHeaderText()).toBe('Something');
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    if (!passed) takeScreenshot();
    await driver.quit();
  });
});
```

With jasmine I would do something like:

```
  var passed = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.results().passed();
```

But I cannot find something similar for Jest. Maybe there is another solution like taking a screenshot on each failing expect? I tried a try/catch around the expect, but then the test always passes...

How can I check with Jest if my test failed in the afterEach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the jasmine object can be used in Jest tests, but the currentSpec has been removed in the 2.x version.

I have found an alternative with the use of jasmine custom reports. Just make sure you also move the `driver.quit()` to the reporter as you might still need the driver after the test.

Here is an simple example for the reporter handling failing tests at the end of the test:

```
const reporter = {
  specDone: async (result) => {
    if (result.status === 'failed') {
      takeScreenshot(result.description);
    }
    await driver.quit();
  },
};

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

describe('Page', () => {  
  it('should contain Text in the header', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const page = new Page(driver);

    // Act
    await page.open();

    // Assert
    expect(await page.getHeaderText()).toBe('Something');
  });
});
```

Comment: The downside of taking a screenshot in `specDone` is that it runs after `afterEach`, so if there's something in `afterEach` that, say, navigates back a few screens, the screenshot you end up taking won't be representative of the actual error. I'll add an answer that still allows you to do it right after the `test` fails.

Answer (score 7):

### Store current spec results in Jasmine and access it in `afterEach`.

*@Niels van Reijmersdal is on the right track. However, the downside of taking a screenshot in `specDone` is that it runs **after** `afterEach`, so if there's something in `afterEach` that, say, navigates back a few screens, the screenshot you end up taking won't be representative of where the error took place. Here's an answer that allows you to take a screenshot immediately after the error occurs.*

1. Add a custom Jasmine reporter for `specStarted` and store the spec results to `jasmine.currentTest`.

   ```js
   jasmine.getEnv().addReporter( {
     specStarted: result => jasmine.currentTest = result
   } );
   ```

   The unintuitive thing about this is that even though we're storing this in `specStarted` before the results are in, `jasmine.currentTest` stores a reference to the `result` object which will get updated dynamically as the spec runs so when we access it in our `afterEach`, it will be holding the results of the spec properly.
2. Check for `failedExpectations` in your `afterEach` and take a screenshot if there's been any failures.

   ```js
   afterEach( async () => {
     if ( jasmine.currentTest.failedExpectations.length > 0 ) { // There has been a failure.
       await driver.takeScreenshot();
     }
   } );
   ```

Comment: Nice, my current team is not using Jest, but it looks very promising.

Comment: Does it work when using [test.concurrent](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testconcurrentname-fn-timeout)?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example how I solved it in my project:
(Assuming that afterEach is used only for taking screenshots and not for cleanup and other navigates)

```
const testIt = (name, action) => {
    test(name, async () => {        
        try {         
            await action()} 
        catch (error) {           
            await screenshots.createScreenshot(page) //take screenshot 
            throw error
        }
    })
  }

describe('Test scenario 1', () => {
   
    testIt('test1 will Pass', async () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true)
    })
        
    testIt('test2 will Fail', async () => {
        expect(true).toBe(false)
    })

    afterEach(async () => {
        //ignored
    })

})
```

I use jest-html-reporters, and only failed tests will have attachment there (this solution did not require any other configurations).
Result:

- test1 - passed, no screenshot
- test2 - failed, has screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Provided answers to not work anymore, because jest is using `jest-circus` now, not `jasmine`. See thread with possible solutions: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5292#issuecomment-1328993445

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34164615)