# How to run function when any test fails - Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, puppeteer

I want to run a `function` / `task` whenever any `jest` test fails. Instead of wrapping all of my test's with `try` / `catch` or add an `if` check, is there a way I can utilize the `afterEach` ?

If the test fails then I want it to fail, just run a separate function.

For example:

```
test('nav loads correctly', async () => {
    const listItems = await page.$$('[data-testid="navBarLi"]')

    expect(listItems.length).toBe(4)

    if (listItems.length !== 4)
      await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'})

  })
```

This is adding an if check... But I want something more robust for all of my tests.

Comment: What will be the purpose of this function? will it log the failure?

Comment: basically I want to take a screenshot when a test fails.. (I'm using google's puppeteer). AfterEach would work if it had access to the current test. To check if it passes or fails. But looks like this is not built in https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5292

Comment: The other option I could think of, is implementing a [reporter](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#reporters-array-modulename-modulename-options) (in addition to the default one).

Comment: there is discussion in https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer/issues/43 with some workarounds. Also [jest-screenshot-reporter](https://github.com/alexeyraspopov/jest-webdriver/blob/master/packages/jest-screenshot-reporter/modules/JestScreenshotReporter.js) sounds like exactly what you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if test failed in afterEach of Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000137/check-if-test-failed-in-aftereach-of-jest)

Answer (score 5):

@Tyler Clark I haven't attempted this with `afterEach`, but I suspect you could apply something similar this [my SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258872/4064901). (pasting a version of it below for context - altered to work with `afterEach`)

```js
const GLOBAL_STATE = Symbol.for('$$jest-matchers-object');

describe('Describe test', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    if (global[GLOBAL_STATE].state.snapshotState.matched !== 1) {
      console.log(`\x1b[31mWARNING!!! Catch snapshot failure here and print some message about it...`);
    }
  });

  it('should test something', () => {
    expect({}).toMatchSnapshot(); // replace {} with whatever you're trying to test
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### Store current spec results in Jasmine and access it in `afterEach`.

1. Add a custom Jasmine reporter for `specStarted` and store the spec results to `jasmine.currentTest`.

   ```js
   jasmine.getEnv().addReporter( {
     specStarted: result => jasmine.currentTest = result
   } );
   ```

   The unintuitive thing about this is that even though we're storing this in `specStarted` before the results are in, `jasmine.currentTest` stores a reference to the `result` object which will get updated dynamically as the spec runs so when we access it in our `afterEach`, it will be holding the results of the spec properly.
2. Check for `failedExpectations` in your `afterEach` and take a screenshot if there's been any failures.

   ```js
   afterEach( async () => {
     if ( jasmine.currentTest.failedExpectations.length > 0 ) { // There has been a failure.
       await driver.takeScreenshot(); // Or whatever else you want to do when a failure occurs.
     }
   } );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why *not* use try/catch?

If you don't like how it looks, you can hide the ugliness away in a function:

```
function runAssertion(assertion, onFailure) {
    try {
        assertion();
    } catch (exception) {
        onFailure();
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
test('nav loads correctly', async () => {
    const listItems = await page.$$('[data-testid="navBarLi"]')

    runAssertion(
        () => { expect(listItems.length).toBe(4) },
        () => { await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'}) }
    )
})
```

This is the approach our team has taken to avoid using try/catch everywhere.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using `toMatchSnapshot`

Comment: @Jeremy Sorry, I've never used `toMatchSnapshot`. It must not throw an exception when it fails.

Comment: that's exactly it - see [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5802). My [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258872/4064901) addresses a solution

Comment: You shouldn't have to write a method to be able to get the test status from a test runner... this is a workaround at best, but still kind of sloppy imo