# Check if test failed in 'afterEach' of Jest without jasmine

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, jestjs

I want to be able to check whether one my Jest tests succeeded or failed. There is [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000137/check-if-test-failed-in-aftereach-of-jest?answertab=votes#tab-top) on this topic, but the solution uses Jasmine, is kind hacky, and is by no means guaranteed to continue working with future versions of Jasmine or Jest. I'm looking for a solution to this problem which doesn't tack on a large dependency like Jasmine.

Comment: This sounds more like a feature request for Jest than a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could track the test status by creating a flag in the test suite.

**Explanation.**

Create a flag `testStatus` in the `describe block` and two counter variables ( if you want to get the count of the `Failed` and `passed` test cases). And set the initial value of the flag `testStatus` to `false`.

```
describe("Should count the test", () => {
  let testStatus = false;
  let passTests = 0;
  let failedTest = 0;

  //.... test cases

});
```

And in each test case at the end of the test case set the value of the `flag` `testStatus` to `true`.

```
it("Should fail/Pass", () => {
    expect(false).toBe(true);
    testStatus = true;
});
```

The line after `expect` will only run if the test cases executed successfully, Otherwise the `flag` value will remain `false`.

And now in `afterEach` we can check if the `flag` value (`testStatus`) is true or false.

if the value is false then the test case got failed and if the value is `true` means test case executed successfully.

And reset the value of the `flag (testStatus)` back to false.

```
afterEach(() => {
    if (testStatus) {
      passTests += 1;
    } else {
      failedTest += 1;
    }

    testStatus = false;
});
```

Hope this will be helpful.

**Live example.**

[image: Edit Track the test case status in jest]