# Using AfterEach with different file module in NodeJS getting different values

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, puppeteer, asynchronous-javascript

I'm quite new in using Node JS, and I have been working on a test script that take screenshots whenever a test fails. And I'm trying to do this without the use of Jasmine reporter. I tried to use this approach instead [Check if test failed in 'afterEach' of Jest without jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868591/check-if-test-failed-in-aftereach-of-jest-without-jasmine), however, I'm working with different files  I have a file fail_test.spec.js that is used as my main file, and a test_fail1.js as another testscript file. Here is what happening, my test on fail_test.spec.js works fine with the use of AfterEach, just like in the link, it gives me "true" value if the test passed and "false" value when the test fails and it performs screenshot. The problem is the test_fail1.js is also being check by the AfterEach and it constantly gives of a "false" value even if the test passed. I do intend to use AfterEach with the test_fail1.js and on other tests in the future. So my questions are:

1. Why does the test_fail1.js only gives of constant "false" value?
2. Is there any work around with this? Because I just only need to know the status of the test in every testscripts within or with other files (ex.fail_test1.js, fail_test2.js, and so on)

Comment: Could you post some minimal code to help diagnose and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.